# reinstalling ubuntu with wubi to repartition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, wubi

So, here's the issue: My ubuntu partition is too small. I was running 12.04 and went to 13.04 but lost support and disk space in the process.

So, I figured I could just log back onto windows (I dual boot) and reinstall with "wubI" because I still have bios.

So my questions are..

1. do I have to manually remove ubuntu first?
2. Will reinstalling it over the current version repartition my drive? Or what?

I don't feel super safe repartitioning it manually as I don't know what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You do not have to remove Ubuntu first. You can reinstall over the current version. You should also consider using 14.04 as it has better hardware support for most systems, and will be supported for much longer than 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize partitions using gparted. That way, you don't have to reinstall Ubuntu.

1. Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)
2. Install gparted using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```
3. Launch it via dash or by running

   ```
   sudo gparted
   ```
4. Select the partition you want to resize and click the 'Resize' button.
5. When you're done making changes, hit 'Apply'.

If you have a question regarding that, please upload a screenshot of gparted so we can see what you want to / can do.

Comment: I've looked into gparted before but I don't have the option to resize/move and I don't have near enough unallocated space to reassign anyways. 286GB for ntfs and only ~10GB for / . So I figured I could just reinstall due to my inexperience.

Comment: Why don't you have the option to resize/move? In case it is grayed out, try using an Ubuntu live CD/USB stick. Also make sure the Windows partition is unmounted before you try to resize it.